# Why can't I stop the sound effect for adjusting volume level?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

If I go to Settings --> Sound, then there's a checkmark that says "Play feedback when volume is changed." I unchecked it, but the sound effect is still there.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Newest, I suppose? 10.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer needed to be restarted before effect took place.

Interesting to note, holding shift while adjusting volume now causes there to be sound, rather than the reverse effect prior to me implementing this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use shift while changing volume. There shouldn't be any sound.

Comment: In new OS X 10.10 Yosemite use Command button instead of Shift button

Answer (score 1):

This is to test if your preferences settings are been saved:

In Finder hold the Alt key and click on Go tab

Click on Library

In the new window (the Library) sort by Date saved.

In the Folder Preferences there is a file called

```
com.apple.systempreferences.plist
```

Leave that window open and now change the settings in your sys pref Sound.

Observe the file com.apple.systempreferences.plist changing the date/Time saved.

If not then we need you to fix your Permissions !.

Comment: I opened settings just now and watched the time change for Created/Modified. So, it *seems* I have permission.

Comment: Darn, so it is not that, was hoping it was.

Answer (score 1):

The setting for "Play feedback when volume is changed" in stored in ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist file with the key com.apple.sound.beep.feedback.

If the key value is set to 0 then feedback sound is disabled. If they key value is set to 1 then the feedback sound is enabled.

If you want to see the current value that is set you can run the following command in terminal:

defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist com.apple.sound.beep.feedback

That will output either a 0 or 1. 0 = off, 1 = on.

To set the feedback sound to disabled, run the following command in terminal:

defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist -int 0

To re enable feedback sound run the same command but replace the 0 with a 1.

Comment: The number is zero but I still hear the sound.